# Any suggestions to deserialize this json with Gson?

Tags: android, json

Any suggestions to deserialize this json with Gson ?
{
  "0": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pepe"
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "pipo"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "pato"
  }
  ...
  n objects
}

Comment: maybe you can show us your java so we can help you better. were not here to write out the function(s) needed.

Comment: I just need ideas, I use retrofit, you map the classes, but in this case, they are objects, if it were an arrays it would be simple, but the api is designed like that.

Comment: i dont use gson... i use the java JSONObject/JSONArray classes. easier (in my opinion). but again, we can give you ideas... but ideas are already out there. you just need to look. there are plenty of great tutorials on gson.. i also think using an array of objets would be easier to parse. like [{id:1,name:pepe}, {id:2,name:papa}, etc]

Comment: and using JSONObject / JSONArray. what would be the way?

Comment: google.com will show you the way. come back when you have code to show.

Comment: Convert the Json string to Hashmap<String, JsonObject>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the Json string to Hashmap like below using Google's Gson, then you can interate through the hashmap

```
String jsonString = "Your JSON string";
HashMap<String, JsonObject> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, JsonObject>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Oh man, you saved my day!!! Thank you so much for clear explanation!!!

Comment: @Jacsel Glad that it helped you...